# Confusing proxy issue using PhantomJS C#

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

So basically I am trying to automate the web. I'm doing this by using Selenium and PhantomJS driver.

In addition to this I am doing it using a proxy. This is where the problems start.

Without the proxy it's working just fine. Using it doesn't. I'm having big trouble trying to debug this.

This is what I am using now to set the proxy:

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.ProxyType = "http";

service.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy=", proxyL));
```

I feel like I have tried every single Google result regarding this and none of the different variants have worked so far. If there is anyone who's got experience with using the PhantomJS diver with a proxy I would love some help.

EDIT:

I am now using this code to set the proxy:

```
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, new Dictionary<string, string>

{
            {"proxyType", "none"},
            {"httpProxy", proxyL}
});
```

The console window dows show that I'm using the proxy. But it still isn't.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using the PhantomJS driver. I have changed the code a bit and the console window does show me that im using the proxy. But if I for example try and go to a "check my IP site" and take a screenshot, it still shows me my normal IP.

Comment: @Jomasdf Does c# have something like capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.cliArguments(myargs)) where myargs is some sorty of array/list with "--proxy=host:port","proxy-type=http|socks". Do not use proxy-type=none as this disables proxying. Is the site using an SSL certifcate and your SSL is up to date? Do you need to autenticate "--proxy-auth=username:pass". Finally, if all else fails, are you sure you are not xforwarding your IP from the proxy server (look for an xforwarded header with your ip).

Comment: Late answear, but this did work for me and still does:  service.Proxy = proxyIp;
                  service.ProxyType = "http";
            //    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, new Dictionary<string, string>
            //{
            //    {"proxyType", "http"},
            //    {"httpProxy", proxyIp},
            //    {"proxy-auth", auth}

            //});

              //  service.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy-auth={0}", auth));
                service.ProxyAuthentication = auth;